# Example, how to use huge json in erlyDTL?

Tags: erlang

I have **json**

```
{
    "_total": 824,
    "_links": "self",
    "top": [
        {
            "viewers": 80896,
            "channels": 1177,
            "game": {
                "name": "League of Legends",
                "_id": 21779,
            }
        },
        {
            "viewers": 31211,
            "channels": 232,
            "game": {
                "name": "Dota 2",
                "_id": 29595,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

how best displayed "top" list? I try:

```
Tuple = jsx:decode(unicode:characters_to_binary(Json)),
[_, _, Top] = Tuple,
Games = element(2, Top);
```

but how using this in **template**?

```
{% for v in games %}
    {{ v.viewers }}<br><br>
    {{ v.channel }}<br><br>
    {{ v.game.name }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

not work, and then show {{ games.game.name }} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you did is fine, it just need a few updates, you shouldn't pass Games to the template, instead you should use top as the key, as an example, build a rebar file like:

```
%rebar.config
{deps, [
    {erlydtl, ".*", {git, "git@github.com:erlydtl/erlydtl.git", "HEAD"}},
    {jsx, ".*", {git, "git@github.com:talentdeficit/jsx.git", "HEAD"}}
]}.
```

then run:

```
rebar get-deps
rebar compile
```

Now define a template with the suggested update, named `template.dtl`:

```
{% for v in top %}
    {{ v.viewers }}<br><br>
    {{ v.channels }}<br><br>
    {{ v.game.name }}<br><br>
{% endfor %}
```

Start an erlang shell:

```
erl -pa ./deps/erlydtl/ebin/ -pa ./deps/merl/ebin/ -pa ./deps/jsx/ebin/
```

and execute the commands which should display the template as expected

```
Json = "{
    \"_total\": 824,
    \"_links\": \"self\",
    \"top\": [
        {
            \"viewers\": 80896,
            \"channels\": 1177,
            \"game\": {
                \"name\": \"League of Legends\",
                \"_id\": 21779,
            }
        },
        {
            \"viewers\": 31211,
            \"channels\": 232,
            \"game\": {
                \"name\": \"Dota 2\",
                \"_id\": 29595,
            }
        }
    ]
}".
Tuple = jsx:decode(unicode:characters_to_binary(Json)).
erlydtl:compile("./template.dtl", test).
test:render(Tuple).
```

which gives the expecte output

```
{ok,[[[<<"\n    ">>,"80896",<<"<br><br>\n    ">>,"1177",
   <<"<br><br>\n\t">>,<<"League of Legends">>,<<"<br><br>\n">>],
  [<<"\n    ">>,"31211",<<"<br><br>\n    ">>,"232",
   <<"<br><br>\n\t">>,<<"Dota 2">>,<<"<br><br>\n">>]],
 <<"\n">>]}
```

in few words, in your template, replace `games` with `top` and pass `Tuple` to the template